# How to find first cell that contains data with respect to column?

Tags: excel, vba

I am using

```
lastRowIndex = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
```

to find the last row with data.

How do I find the first row? I found some code with `activesheet.usedrange` but it does not work for me since for b column the first data starts at second row, but in A column it starts at 4th row. I need a function that finds me the number 4.

Comment: `firstRowIndex = .Cells(1, "A").End(xlDown).row` and deal with the possibility row 1 contains data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an alternative version without the use of `CountA()` is the following:

```
Function firstrow2(col As Range) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    Set f = col.Find("*", after:=col.Cells(col.Parent.Rows.Count))  '<--| look for any value in given column from its row 1 (included) downwards
    If Not f Is Nothing Then firstrow2 = f.Row '<--| if found then return its row index
End Function
```

which is returning `0` if there is no data in passed column

should you make it a little more robust and handle a *wrong* passed range (not an entire column or wider then a column) you can use the following:

```
Function FirstRow(col As Range) As Long
    Dim f As Range
    With col.Columns(1).EntireColumn
        Set f = .Find("*", after:=.Cells(.Rows.Count))  '<--| look for any value from row 1 (included)
    End With
    If Not f Is Nothing Then FirstRow4 = f.Row '<--| if found then return its row index
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim col As Range
Set col = Columns(10)

If Application.CountA(col) > 0 Then
    Debug.Print "first data: " & col.Find("*", after:=col.Cells(Rows.Count)).Row
Else
    Debug.Print "no data"
End If
```